# Wait till completion of script [ ajax ]

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

the below code  if the ajax call i make to my run.py and then displays the output in a html tag. the script run.py runs for over 2 mins. But in the js script below. as soon as the script has begun to run. the output ( initial lines of the output) will be displayed in the html tag. the remaining part of the script won't be displayed.

```
$(document).ready(function(){   

$(sub).click(function(){ 
    alert("connecting to host")
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'/cgi-bin/run.py', 
                dataType: 'html',                                        
                success:function (z) {
                     $('#output').html(z);



                }


        });

        }) ;
});
```

I'd like to know if there is any function in ajax to wait till completion of script  (Not just execution of script. but wait till end ) and then display entire output to the html tag.

Here is my python script:

```
import sys, os
import cgi, cgitb

    def __init__(self, address, username, password):
    # connects to host


    def sendShell(self, command):
     #opens shell

    def process(self):

                while self.shell.recv_ready():
                    info += self.shell.recv(1024)
                output = str(info, "utf8")
                print(output)

hostname = "z.com"
password = "yyy"
username = "dd"   
connection = ssh(hostname, username, password)
connection.openShell()
connection.sendShell("date");
```

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery.ajax()` has an option `async: false`, however I'd advise against it and just do whatever you need in ajax callbacks. Also, it's deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the async flag of the $.Ajax function to false is almost correct, yet in your case the script needs to run for long time so you need to consider using Long Polling for such a request.

The reason is because the browsers have max timeout for ajax calls and usually is set to 1 min depending on the browser(so in your case after 1 min the client / browser stops the connection and wants the response, but you want it to wait until its done and only then send the response back).
So to overcome this you will have to send once a 20 sec or once of the max timeout another request to the py script to check if its done.

**Code snippet for javascript side:**

```
function isDone(timestamp) {
    timestamp = timestamp || null;

    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'/cgi-bin/run.py', 
        dataType: 'json',                                       
        data: { "timestamp": timestamp },
        timeout: 20000, // Or to whatever the max-timeout is, haven't checked that with jQuery.
        success: function (response) {
            if (response.done === false) {

                isDone(Date.now ());
            } else {
                // got the results, can continue.
                $('#output').html(response.output);
            }
        }
    });
}

isDone();
```

I'm not sure how the pyton script should look like, if you want you can share it with me and I will try to complete the server side.
Basically what you should do there is to set the timeout of the script to the max, and return the correct response to the client.

**JSON response should look like this:**

```
{
   "done": true, // or false if the script timed out.
   "output": html, // the variable that should contain the output when the py script is done, if its not done just send a null or don't send it back to the client at all.
   "timestamp": time.time() // if im not wrong that's how you get timestamp in py

}
```

**Server-side in pseudo code:**

```
Dynamcally or under setting, configure python script execution time to max or rather to 3 min, sense you mentioned it takes 2 min.

if (timestamp === null) { // first ajax call to this script.
    - Start long processing task.
    - Write the output to a file.
}

do { //  check this code block every 1 sec
    if (the file you are writing to was created and is complete / unlocked) {
        - Read from that file the content, save it into a variable and delete the file from your system.
        - Output the above mentioned response with done set to true and the current timestamp.
        - Break outside of the loop
    }

    if (timed out) { // basically check if 20 second passed sense starting timestamp.
        - Output the above mentioned response with done set to false and the current timestamp.
        - Break outside of the loop.
    }

    sleep for 1 sec, you don't want to kill your CPU usage.
} while (true)
```

Comment: import sys, os
import cgi, cgitb

    def __init__(self, address, username, password):
    # connects to host
 

    def sendShell(self, command):
     #opens shell

    def process(self):
       
                while self.shell.recv_ready():
                    alldata += self.shell.recv(1024)
                strdata = str(alldata, "utf8")
                print(strdata)
      
hostname = "z.com"
password = "yyy"
username = "dd"   
connection = ssh(hostname, username, password)
connection.openShell()
connection.sendShell("date");

Comment: have added the snippet in my post. @Eden Thanks for your valuable input. where shall i add the json part of snippet in my code?

Comment: Well i'm not well familiar with py syntax. In pseudo code it should look like this..editing my answer

Comment: Ok @Rithesh I have updated my answer. Hope that gives you a basic idea how that might work..